# Is it possible to run a CMS and Angular on the same domain?

Tags: angular, content-management-system

I'd like to run a CMS, for example WordPress, and an application built with Angular2 on the same domain.

It should work as following:

- http://example.com/ -> CMS
- http://example.com/about -> CMS
- http://example.com/dashboard -> Angular application

Anyone know how I can achieve something like this?

Comment: what you tried so far and what problems you are facing ?

Comment: I currently have a full Angular2 website, but I rather have the actual read-only website handled by a CMS, rather than writing HTML, CSS by myself. I'd also like to be able to update the website using a CMS rather than pushing new code to the website everytime I want to update something.

Answer (score 0):

took a while for this to be supported anywhere but for future viewers of this question now it is! Our ASP.Net Core CMS ([www.lynicon.com](http://www.lynicon.com)) solves exactly this problem. ASP.Net Core works with Angular by hosting all the built Angular site within its file structure. It then diverts requests not defined as handled elsewhere to the Angular SPA. You can define url patterns to be handled by the CMS and others that will be handled by the SPA.

Lynicon also allows you to automatically pick up data from the CMS in Angular when the Angular route changes, so you can feed CMS data into an Angular template. It also manages live preview so you can see the appropriate content editor for the current route alongside the Angular SPA. See [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1251717/Tightly-integrating-a-lightweight-CMS-with-Angular) for more.